# Does Next.js fetch() API have the cache option in PAGE ROUTER as with the APP ROUTER

Tags: next.js, next.js13

The question is same as title. As I read here in App Router https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch . Next.js extends the native Web fetch() API to allow each request on the server to set its own persistent caching semantics. Does it work the same way in Page Router because I didn't manage to find any resources about this.

If not, is there any way to make this feasible on Page Router

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

So, in Page Router we have benefits of Static Site Generation (SSG), Server-Side Rendering (SSR), and Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) are now available through one API That is introduced in Next.13
Blog:- https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#data-fetching